# Is there a way to fix the slow space switching animation in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, spaces

I'm a developer and use spaces extensively. I have my terminal in one space, my editor in another, etc.

When I use ctrl + arrow key to switch to the left or right the animation is incredibly slow (better than in older versions, but still). This is killing it for me.

Is there a way to turn this animation off or influence its speed?

I know there was a command in Snow Leopard that could do that

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-swoosh-animation-off -bool YES
```

but it doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know a trick to fix this?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I filled a bug for this with Apple. The Radar number is 19169435. I would encourage you to also file the report at https://bugreport.apple.com/. Note in your description that it is a duplicate of the above bug report number to help the support staff categorize and prioritize this bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using TotalSpaces (http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/), a small tool a bit more flexible than spaces. There you can switch off transitions in the preferences.

Comment: TotalSpace is not a viable alternative since OS X 10.11 (that brings the System Integrity Protection). :(