# Is it possible to change, reduce, or eliminate the "swiping" motion between Desktops in Yosemite?

Tags: mission-control, animation

I do a lot of swapping back and forth between desktops, and I find the animation very distracting. Can I turn this animation off? How about the "zoom" animation for the Dashboard, Lauchpad, and Mission Control / Expose?

I'm on a MacBook Pro with Yosemite.

Comment: You may want to try this thread:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion

Comment: @MickeyMartin dang, that's not hopeful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to fix the slow space switching animation in Yosemite?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159704/is-there-a-way-to-fix-the-slow-space-switching-animation-in-yosemite)